# Convert ES6 class to typescript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following ES6 class.

```
class Http {
    isFormData;
    url;
    token;
    data;

    constructor() {
        this.isFormData = false;
        this.url = '';
        this.token = '';
        this.data = {};
    }

    /** Set url */
    setUrl(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    /** Set data */
      setData(data: Object) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
}

export default new Http();
```

I want to make it a typescript class. I tried but some properties are not identified properly. How can I make it a typescript class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the types of your properties. I also suggest you make them private:

```
class Http {
    private isFormData: boolean;
    private url: string;
    private token: string;
    private data: Object;

    constructor() {
        this.isFormData = false;
        this.url = '';
        this.token = '';
        this.data = {};
    }

    /** Set url */
    setUrl(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    /** Set data */
    setData(data: Object) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
}

export default new Http();
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to export your class with  `export class Http` so you can import it 
as `import {Http} from './http'`

```
 export  class Http {
 isFormData: boolean;
 url: string;
 token: string;
 data: Object;

constructor() {
    this.isFormData = false;
    this.url = '';
    this.token = '';
    this.data = {};
}

/** Set url */
setUrl(url: string) {
    this.url = url;
    return this;
}
/** Set data */
setData(data: Object) {
    this.data = data;
    return this;
}
```

}